# Bean definition in grails 3 plugin

Tags: grails-plugin

I have created grails 3 plugin and resources.groovy file in grails-app/conf/spring. I have defined bean in resources.groovy file, but when I inject that bean in tests it's value is null. What is wrong?

Comment: I have used beans in grails, but without plugin. Maybe if you add some code I can help you.